# manifest for custom function and excel custom function in one office.js add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, manifest, office-addins

I am trying to create an add-in in excel with taskpane (in react), custom function and excel custom function. So I have tried to copy key part of manifest of excel custom function to manifest  of excel add-in in react. Key part of combined manifest is as follow.
Requirements,

```
<Requirements>
<Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
<Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
<Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
</Sets>
</Requirements>
```

DefaultSettings

```
<DefaultSettings>
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
</DefaultSettings>
```

Hosts

```
<Hosts>
<Host xsi:type="Workbook">
<!-- Custom function start -->
<AllFormFactors>
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
<Page>
<SourceLocation resid="MyCustFunctions.Page.Url"/>
</Page>
<Metadata>
<SourceLocation resid="MyCustFunctions.Metadata.Url"/>
</Metadata>
<Namespace resid="MyCustFunctions.Namespace"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
</AllFormFactors>
<!-- Custom function end -->
<!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
<DesktopFormFactor>
…………….code for task pane and custom function.
</DesktopFormFactor>
</Host>
</Hosts>
```

Resources

```
<Resources>
 All resources.
<Resources>
```

When I try to do

> npm run build

for this add-in, there is not files in “dist” folder related to excel custom function (ie .JS, .Html, .Json). basically, I am not able hook function.js saved in src folder with the manifest.
I have tried to review manifest of excel custom function, I could not understand how scr/function/function.html is hooked/connected in manifest.xml
Can anyone advise how can I solve this problem.